# Waiting for data initiated in a constructor via API to be populated

Tags: angular

I don't know Angular and reactive programming so well and I am struggling with this problem.

I have a Service called `ManagerService` that stores some static data used by my app.  The constructor of this service calls a WebService which retrieves the data from the service.

```
  constructor(private apiService: APIService) {

      this.apiService.getData()
        .subscribe((result: APIResponse) => {
        this.mylist = result.responseObject;
      });
    }
```

This works fine, but takes around 800 -> 900 ms to complete. This will take longer in the future as there will be more data.
This data is static, and also as it takes a while then the API call to the server should only be executed once when the service is initiated.

In the meantime I have a component which when loaded initiates the service.
Then in `ngOnInit()` it calls another method on the service to return a random item some of this static data.

```
this.item = this.manager.getRandomItem();
```

This will then be called again later multiple times.

This is the method in `ManagerService` which is called

```
public getRandomItem() {            
    const index = Math.floor((Math.random() * this.myList.length) + 1);   
    return this.myList[index];
  }
```

The problem is that when the `getRandomItem()` method is called the first time, then the variable `myList` is not yet populated;

The current flow of the program is:

1. Constructor is called, initiates API call
2. getRandomItem() called (fails)
3. API call returns and myList is populated

I can't figure out a way to get this method to wait for the data to be populated in `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.apiService.getData().pipe(map(list => getRandomItem(list))).subscribe(result 
  => ...)
}

public getRandomItem(myList: []) {            
   const index = Math.floor((Math.random() * myList.length) + 1);   
   return myList[index];
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't really help and it moves the responsibility of retrieving the static data out of the service and into the component.  So now the static data can no longer be used by multiple components.